# Issue downloading Links that end with .zip

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to bulk download of a bunch of hyperlink zipped files from a web page. I am using Python and beautifulsoup. I wrote the code in a notepad and saved it as a .py . Then I ran the code using my pc's command console and it returned no errors and didn't download anything. In trying to solve this issue I wanted to make sure the code was locating all of the links to download. I added a print statement to show me the number of links found and it is returning a blank field in the command console. I'm not sure why the code is not seeing the links to download the .zip files. On the web page the hyperlink is located in a table , I'm not sure if maybe that is why it is not finding the files.

I expected the code to help me bulk download all
Here is the code I am using:

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL
url = "https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5248eb6412648ec8cbd46838adb86e9#data"

# Directory
download_dir = r"C: My Drive"

# GET request
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Extract all <a> tags containing download links
links = soup.find_all("a", href=True)

# Print all the links found
print("All links found on the webpage:")
for link in links:
    print(link["href"])

# Download each file with a .zip extension
for link in links:
    href = link["href"]
    if href.endswith(".zip"):
        file_url = href
        file_name = file_url.split("/")[-1]
        file_path = os.path.join(download_dir, file_name)
        print("Downloading", file_name)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(requests.get(file_url).content)

print("All files downloaded successfully.")
```

Comment: `download_dir = r"C: My Drive"`  this seems an invalid path

Comment: I just removed my actual directory

Comment: Have you opened up the URL in a web browser and looked at the _source_? Like many modern websites, what you get when you download that URL is a skeleton of a website and a call to a javascript function that requests and displays the actual content asynchronously. There are no HTML elements with "a" tags in the file downloaded from that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can get the `.zip` URLs from this site:

```py
import re

import requests


def get_id(url):
    return re.search(r"id=([a-f0-9]+)", url).group(1)


base_url = (
    "https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a5248eb6412648ec8cbd46838adb86e9#data"
)

id_ = get_id(base_url)

api_url = f"https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/{id_}?f=json"
data = requests.get(api_url).json()
org_id = data["orgId"]

params = {
    "f": "json",
    "where": "1=1",
    "returnGeometry": "false",
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
    "outFields": "*",
    "orderByFields": "FID ASC",
    "resultOffset": "0",
    "resultRecordCount": "9999",
    "cacheHint": "true",
    "quantizationParameters": '{"mode":"edit"}',
}

api_url2 = f"https://services1.arcgis.com/{org_id}/arcgis/rest/services/Statewide_Contours/FeatureServer/0/query"

data = requests.get(api_url2, params=params).json()
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, f in enumerate(data["features"], 1):
    print(i, f["attributes"]["ContoursURL"])
```

Prints:

```
...

98 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Leavenworth_2ft_Contours.zip
99 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Chautauqua_2ft_Contours.zip
100 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Rooks_2ft_Contours.zip
101 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Reno_2ft_Contours.zip
102 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Gray_2ft_Contours.zip
103 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Wabaunsee_2ft_Contours.zip
104 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Sedgwick_2ft_Contours.zip
105 https://dasc.blob.core.windows.net/public/webdata/catalog/elevation/Contours/KS_2FootContours/Jackson_2ft_Contours.zip
```